# Dataset of Business Schools in the US

Tags: data-request, data.gov, government, finance, education

Is is there a dataset of all the business schools in the US, with total undergrad enrollment in the Business School, Dean (and Associate Dean's) name and email address, and if there is an online component.  Thanks!

Ideally, it should look like this

[image: Screenshot of list]

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you looking for what you would consider business schools? Are you looking for the enrollment in any business school that may or may not be tied to a larger university/state college system? Defining the scope of your interest more thoroughly would help us help you more. Other than that, my first recommendation is to check out IPEDS on NCES.

Comment: I'm looking for stand alone business schools, as well as Business Schools tied to a larger university.  I check IPEDS (granted I am new to this) and I couldn't find any email addresses of the Dean's in an easy to use dataset.  Thanks so much for commenting!

Comment: admin emails or student emails?

Comment: Dean and Associate Dean's email address (and also career centers email address if possible)

Comment: I do not think you are going to find the email address component for free. This is usually information that takes a lot of effort and companies will sell. My suggestion would be to use open data like IPEDS and then crowdsource, hire cheap labor, etc. to finish the data set. Ideally, publish the data out in the open so folks in the future have it too :)